# How to keep children in a self-referenced table after the parent row gets removed?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a one-to-many relationship in a self-referenced table. I want to keep the children in the table after the parent row is removed from database.

Unfortunately when i'm trying to delete a parent here's what i get:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE
>   constraint "FK_Libraries_Libraries_TemplateId". The conflict occurred
>   in database "xxx", table "dbo.Libraries", column 'TemplateId'.

And here's my configuration:

```
public class Library
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? TemplateId { get; set; }
    public virtual Library Template { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Library> Libraries { get; set; }
}
```

here's how i try to model the behavior:

```
builder.HasMany(library => library.Libraries).WithOne(library => library.Template)
                .HasForeignKey(library => library.TemplateId).IsRequired(false).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set the children's TemplateId to null before deleting the parent.

```
parent.Libraries.Clear();
context.SaveChanges();
```

Should remove the relationship.  Then you can delete the parent.  The children won't be deleted.

Reason: TemplateId is a foreign key pointing at Libraries.  It enforces consistency.  It won't allow you to have a TemplateId pointing at a Library (parent) that doesn't exist.  So, you have to disassociate the children from the parent before you can delete the parent.